# How to divide a large Django project into sub projects for scaling?

Tags: django, git, project, scaling, divide

Django project(e-commerce website) that we need to divide into sub-projects as a Buyer, Seller, and Admin and will create three databases accordingly. So how can we manage the same Models(Schema) in 3 projects if it is updated in one project?.

Comment: create repo for common part of the project and add it to the requements.pip?

Comment: @BearBrown We are speaking regarding model and website performance, etc., not about the package installation.

Comment: i mean may be you need [reusable-apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/)

Answer (score 1):

Django support multiple database features for same project.

This can be achieved by defined multiple database property in **settings.py** as

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'buyer': {
        'NAME': 'buyer',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    },
    'customers': {
        'NAME': 'customers',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
}
```

Need to define router along with this.
**https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers**

Also manually can be selected database by **using** keyword
eg.

```
## fetch
Customer.objects.using('customers').all()
## save
customer_obj.save(using='customers')
```

Ofcourse there is some limitation with multiple database such as

- **Cross-database relations**

  Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or many-to-many
  relationships spanning multiple databases.
- **Behavior of contrib apps**

  Several contrib apps include models, and some apps depend on others. Since cross-database relationships are impossible, this creates some restrictions on how you can split these models across databases:
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#behavior-of-contrib-apps

The official link can be followed for more details:

**https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/**